# How to place element element in row and in each row two under others

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some HTML code in which code I want to place element like is shown in the photo below; an icon and under every icon a word:

[image]

I [image] was able to place element next to each other but I can't put words inside the icon and this is the model which I made.

my code was like this

```
<hr>
    <div class="gridd">

<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span style="grid-area: main;">Ecran</span>
          <br>
          <span style="grid-area:footer;">health</span>
       <span>
 <svg  enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><g></g><g><g><path d="M21,14c0-0.55-0.45-1-1-1h-2v2h2C20.55,15,21,14.55,21,14z"/><path d="M20,17h-2v2h2c0.55,0,1-0.45,1-1C21,17.45,20.55,17,20,17z"/><path d="M12,14h-2v4h2c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h3v-8h-3C12.9,12,12,12.9,12,14z"/><path d="M5,13c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h1.5c1.93,0,3.5-1.57,3.5-3.5S10.43,4,8.5,4H5C4.45,4,4,4.45,4,5c0,0.55,0.45,1,1,1h3.5 C9.33,6,10,6.67,10,7.5S9.33,9,8.5,9H7c-2.21,0-4,1.79-4,4c0,2.21,1.79,4,4,4h2v-2H7C5.9,15,5,14.1,5,13z"/><footer>bonjour</footer></g></g></svg>
     <svg  height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M7 7.07L8.43 8.5c.91-.91 2.18-1.48 3.57-1.48s2.66.57 3.57 1.48L17 7.07C15.72 5.79 13.95 5 12 5s-3.72.79-5 2.07zM12 1C8.98 1 6.24 2.23 4.25 4.21l1.41 1.41C7.28 4 9.53 3 12 3s4.72 1 6.34 2.62l1.41-1.41C17.76 2.23 15.02 1 12 1zm2.86 9.01L9.14 10C8.51 10 8 10.51 8 11.14v9.71c0 .63.51 1.14 1.14 1.14h5.71c.63 0 1.14-.51 1.14-1.14v-9.71c.01-.63-.5-1.13-1.13-1.13zM15 20H9v-8h6v8z"/></svg>

 <svg  style="position: relative;" data-name="Layer 102" viewBox="0 0 100 125" x="0px" y="0px"><path d="M62.12,4H13.38A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,7.63,9.75v80.5A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,13.38,96H62.12a5.76,5.76,0,0,0,5.75-5.75V84.77L71.7,88.6a3.57,3.57,0,0,0,5.06,0L91.32,74a3.56,3.56,0,0,0,0-5.05l-8.49-8.5A3.59,3.59,0,0,0,78.49,60c-1.45-1.94-5-7-5.64-10.07a15.94,15.94,0,0,0-2.48-6.14,28.41,28.41,0,0,0-2.5-3.15V9.75A5.76,5.76,0,0,0,62.12,4Zm3.75,86.25A3.76,3.76,0,0,1,62.12,94H13.38a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.75-3.75V9.75A3.75,3.75,0,0,1,13.38,6H62.12a3.76,3.76,0,0,1,3.75,3.75v29A7.82,7.82,0,0,0,62.13,37a4.91,4.91,0,0,0-2,.16V12.84a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-2.34-2.34H17.66a2.35,2.35,0,0,0-2.35,2.34V78a2.35,2.35,0,0,0,2.35,2.34H57.84A2.34,2.34,0,0,0,60.18,78V75.77l2.13.87a3.55,3.55,0,0,0,.9,3.47l2.66,2.66Zm-27.5-59,9.86,9.86A8.7,8.7,0,0,0,46,42.73a8.47,8.47,0,0,0-1.73,2.38,2.53,2.53,0,0,0-.11,2.35,6.6,6.6,0,0,0-1.74,1.26A5.55,5.55,0,0,0,41,51a2.65,2.65,0,0,0,.22,2.25,5,5,0,0,0-1.46,1,4.07,4.07,0,0,0-1.21,2.32,3.27,3.27,0,0,0,1,2.8l9.54,9.54a29.33,29.33,0,0,0,7.41,5.38l1.63.67v3a.34.34,0,0,1-.34.34H17.66a.35.35,0,0,1-.35-.34V12.84a.35.35,0,0,1,.35-.34H57.84a.34.34,0,0,1,.34.34V37.43L45.63,24.88c-2.18-2.18-4.16-2-5.15-1.76a5,5,0,0,0-3.34,3.63A4.58,4.58,0,0,0,38.37,31.22ZM79,62.08l.17-.17a1.54,1.54,0,0,1,1.11-.46,1.58,1.58,0,0,1,1.12.46l8.49,8.49a1.59,1.59,0,0,1,0,2.23L75.35,87.19a1.61,1.61,0,0,1-2.23,0l-5.25-5.25-1-1-1-1L64.63,78.7a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,0-2.23l1.24-1.24,1-1,1-1ZM68.73,44.88a14.06,14.06,0,0,1,2.16,5.38c.68,3.57,4.63,9.07,6.09,11L67.87,70.4l-1,1-.76.76-.24-.1-3.25-1.33-2.44-1-.07,0c-.32-.16-.62-.35-.93-.52s-.67-.37-1-.57a27,27,0,0,1-4.9-3.89L51.46,62.9l-4-4A1,1,0,0,0,46,60.29l5.84,5.85a29.73,29.73,0,0,0,6.32,4.77c.33.18.66.38,1,.56l.09,0,.91.37,4.39,1.8-1.21,1.22-3.18-1.3-1-.41-1-.41-.79-.33a27.28,27.28,0,0,1-6.84-5L41,58a1.34,1.34,0,0,1-.47-1.14,2.11,2.11,0,0,1,.65-1.16,2.43,2.43,0,0,1,1.49-.77.24.24,0,0,1,.15,0,1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0,1,1,0,0,0,.29-.7,1,1,0,0,0-.29-.71L43,52.26c-.3-.3-.09-.84.15-1.24a4.08,4.08,0,0,1,2.51-2,1,1,0,0,0,1.41,0,1,1,0,0,0,.29-.71,1,1,0,0,0-.29-.71l0,0L46,46.53c-.06-.25.33-1.23,1.48-2.39a4.77,4.77,0,0,1,2.33-1.51,1,1,0,1,0,1.42-1.42h0L39.76,29.79a2.61,2.61,0,0,1-.67-2.56A3,3,0,0,1,41,25c1-.28,2.1.16,3.2,1.25l14,14,1,1,1,1,2.2,2.19A1,1,0,1,0,63.79,43l-3.61-3.61-.09-.09.09,0A2.76,2.76,0,0,1,61.89,39a7.48,7.48,0,0,1,4,2.41c.33.33.66.68,1,1.07s.66.79,1,1.23S68.44,44.46,68.73,44.88Z"/>
         </svg><br><p>bonjour</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

and this the css part of my code and element

```
 svg{
    height:30px;
    width: 30%;
  }
 .gridd{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:

    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer'

    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;


  padding: 10px;
}
```

The real problem is how to place text inside icon like in the picture.

Comment: there is no text inside an icon in both pictures, what exacly do you mean?

Comment: i mean under the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this markdown and styles for every grid item. I hope this can be helpful.

```css
 .gridd{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:

    'left right'

    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gridd-item {
  display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;
  
}

.gridd-item span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gridd-item svg{
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  background: rgb(237,209,94);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237,209,94,1) 0%, rgba(196,134,0,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#edd15e",endColorstr="#c48600",GradientType=1);
  
}
.gridd-item svg path {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.right-part {
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.right-part .gridd-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridd">
<div class="gridd-item" style="grid-area: left;">
<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span>Ecran</span>
      </div>
   
  
  <div class="right-part" style="grid-area: right;">
  <div class="gridd-item">
<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span>Ecran</span>
      </div>
  
  <div class="gridd-item">
<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span>Ecran</span>
      </div>
  
  <div class="gridd-item">
<svg class="bi bi-bullseye" class="bi bi-bullseye" width="1em" height="1em"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="grid-area: menu;"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/></svg>
          <span>Ecran</span>
      </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but there is one other thing how to place three of this next to each others like the picture and next to the first icon in the left if you understand what i mean

Comment: thank you for this but i mean that the first icon screen and there is a space after the icon with text if you can understand what i mean and thak u very much